# Firebase synchronous api

Tags: ios, firebase, grand-central-dispatch, firebase-realtime-database

Parse had synchronous copy for each of the IO api functions. Is it possible to migrate such synchronous ios code from Parse to Firebase? Use the system provided threading library, made by Apple engineers, not the one made by Firebase-Google developers?

Comment: The better way is to use also the asynchronous methods of `Parse`. Synchronous networking is very bad programming habit.

Comment: I'm using grand-central-dispatch on ios and Reactive-java on android

Comment: The main purpose of GCD is performing **a**synchronous tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can synchronously access your Firebase database using their [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to synchronously load the data using the Firebase Database API. While it is probably technically possible to wrap the Firebase Database API with an API that uses lower-level semaphores to block until data becomes available, it would not solve the problem for Firebase.

Firebase works with the concept of synchronizing data, which means that the data may change at any time and your block will be invoked again. That is something that only works well with a callback/block approach, like the one in the Firebase Database API.